# Google Analytic tracking code not working / not installed.

Tags: google-analytics

The code is visible in "view page source" but GA says "**Tracking Not installed**". the website is validated for errors with html5.validator.nu and http://validator.w3.org and there is no error. But still couldn't see the "Tracking Installed" not the realtime activity.

```
<script> (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){ 
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
           m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m) })
           (window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga'); > 
           ga('create', 'UA-40983367-1', 'star-business-directory.com'); 
           ga('send', 'pageview'); </script>
```

here is my site: [star-business-directory.com](http://star-business-directory.com)

Comment: I don't understand are you seeing data in the Realtime reports?  Can you link to the site or post the tracking code, and where you have it placed on the site.

Comment: here is my tracking code: 

> <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

>  ga('create', 'UA-40983367-1', 'star-business-directory.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  </script>

here is my site: [http://star-business-directory.com][1]


  [1]: http://star-business-directory.com

Comment: Are you seeing data in the realtime reports? It can take up to 24 hours for data to be available in the standard reports.  Did you get the code out of the admin section for Google Analytics? This is the tracking code for Universal Analytics.  If your running a Classic analytics account it wont work.

Comment: daily I check and there is nothing in real time and stnardard reports. I pick the code from admin \ property \ tracking info \ tracking code.what is universal analytics and classic analytics? can you explain?

Answer (score 1):

The code is implemented correctly. Please check that your property is properly configured to receive Universal Analytics data. If not, then it will not work.

Regarding Universal or Classic Analytics support, you can find this information if you look in the administrative overview, under "Property".

[image: If you look at the top, you can see a property which does NOT have support for Universal Analytics. Please upgrade.]

If you look at the top, you can see a property which does NOT have support for Universal Analytics. Please upgrade. If you DO have support for it, you should see a green check sign.

Also, are you looking into the correct account and property? You should be seeing real-time data for the property UA-40983367-1.

Comment: Dear I couldn't fine administration \ overview \ universal Analytics upgrade, my tracking is Universal Analytics tracking code. the property is correct.

Comment: I have troubleshooted your implementation and according to what I can find everything seems to be working. GA is sending pixel requests and tag assistant for Chrome reports everything is dandy. Is it still not showing anything?

Comment: now I can see the real time \ over view. it show the active users, but still the Tracking info show " tracking code not installed".

Comment: The tracking code not installed issue *should* disappear once data starts flowing through. I have seen it in my own implementations as well if I check it right after implementation. Perhaps give it a few days to see if you get data, and then see if the "warning" disappears?

Answer (score 0):

The code on your site looks like this:

```
<script> <!-- type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> -->
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-40983367-1', 'star-business-directory.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I believe the problem you are having issues with the HTML comment inside the script tag.  Try and remove the following code.

```
<!-- type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> -->
```

Comment: removed the comments, now activity in realtime \ overview should be visible? am I right?

Comment: Everything else looks right.  I'm hoping this is your problem.

Comment: the updation required 24 hours to affect but in realtime \overview should show the activity. I have nothing. I tried to open in different browsers.